# How do I find out if I have a separate boot partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 16.10, boot-partition

I have Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and I'm planning on dual-booting with Windows 7. The problem is, after I install Windows 7, it will break GRUB. I need to know if I have a separate boot partition so I can restore GRUB to the correct place using an Ubuntu live USB.

This is a picture from GParted. `sda3` is the partition I created for Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: Is this an UEFI system?  sda2 looks like it might be an EFI boot partition, and it has the boot flag set.  An EFI boot partition is not the same as a traditional Ubuntu /boot partition as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Comment: Nope this is a BIOS system.

Comment: That's good news. So how did that 100 M ntfs partition with the boot flag set get there?

Comment: I have no clue I just installed Ubuntu, so do I have a seperate boot partition?

Comment: I am going to say NO. But I am not confident enough to post it as an answer.  Notice that that 100 M partition is not locked/mounted, so Ubuntu is not using it.

Comment: All Windows after XP add a small Boot partition for Windows boot files. Not required, but the default Windows install. Only if you had boot flag on a primary NTFS partition will Windows install to only that partition. But do not confuse a Windows Boot partition with a LInux /boot partition. You only have / (root) which then has all the Linux folders.

Comment: but how come it is flagged as /boot?

Comment: and what is that 100mb partition anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any separate `/boot` partition.

- `/dev/sda1` is your Ubuntu root partition (mount point `/`, which includes all folders that are not mounted from anywhere else, including `/boot` in your case)
- /dev/sda2`and`/dev/sda3`are partitions for Windows, the small one is probably going to be the hidden system partition while the big one will show up as your`C:` drive in Windows.
- `/dev/sda4` is not a "real" partition for data, it's a so-called "extended partition" which means it's just a container that may hold any number of logical volumes (which behave like normal partitions again). Extended partitions are needed because an msdos/MBR partition table can only have 4 primary partitions or 3 primary and one extended (containing any number of logical) partitions.
- `/dev/sda5` is your Linux Swap partition, which is used to swap memory pages out of your RAM when it gets full.

However, to boot using GRUB, you must install it to the disk (`/dev/sda`) and not to any of the partitions, using e.g. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. This should be done from either your running Ubuntu installation on the disk (which will not be possible as you will need to restore GRUB first) or from a `chroot` from a live Ubuntu environment into your mounted Ubuntu partition. It works like this:

1. Boot an Ubuntu live DVD or USB drive. Should be the same architecture (32/64bit) and ideally same release as your installed Ubuntu. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing".
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands to mount your Ubuntu partition and `chroot` into it:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   for x in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys ; do sudo mount --bind "$x" "/mnt/$x" ; done
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. Your terminal prompt should have changed now, as you are now logged in a shell session as root user to your Ubuntu installation on the disk, not the live system. Here type these commands to reinstall GRUB to the disk. Note that we don't need `sudo` here for that reason. Also, the second command could probably be omitted, but it doesn't hurt:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub
   ```
4. Exit the `chroot` session again by typing `exit` or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Unmount all the mounted partitions again:

   ```
   sudo umount -R /mnr
   ```
5. Exit the terminal and reboot from the disk, ejecting the live medium you booted from.

Comment: hey, but I havent installed Windows 7 yet

Comment: But you said you have prepared partitions for it, right? `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` are both NTFS partitions (Windows file system) and not mounted by Ubuntu at the moment, so they are not used by it. They're also empty, so it seems like you just manually created them.

Comment: yes, but I only created one partition and that was /dev/sda3/

Comment: Well, obviously *someone* or *something* must have created it... v(^_^)v

Comment: so I dont have a seperate boot partition so should I delete it?(dev/sda2

Comment: Do with it whatever you want. It's probably empty anyway, at the moment. I'd just delete both NTFS partitions and let the Windows installer create the partitions there itself. (Make sure you have a backup of your important data though, in case something goes wrong and it attempts to overwrite a used partition. With Windows one never knows...)